# Set different compiler flags for different source files with f2py and numpy.distutils

Tags: python, numpy, distutils, f2py

I have a python wrapper for a set of Fortran90 codes, which I am building with f2py and packaging with numpy.distutils

My issue is that one source file (out of a large and complex project) will not build unless compiler optimization is turned off. Thus I'm trying to figure out how to set *different* compiler optimization for different source files that get passed to numpy.distutils.

The relevant `setup.py` file currently looks like this:

```
def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
    global config
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    from numpy.distutils.fcompiler import get_default_fcompiler

    # figure out which compiler we're going to use
    compiler = get_default_fcompiler()
    # set some fortran compiler-dependent flags
    f90flags = []
    if compiler == 'gnu95':
        f90flags.append('-fno-range-check')
        f90flags.append('-ffree-form')
    elif compiler == 'intel' or compiler == 'intelem':
        f90flags.append('-132')
    #  Need zero-level optimization to avoid build problems with one file only!
    f90flags.append('-O0')
    #  Suppress all compiler warnings (avoid huge CI log files)
    f90flags.append('-w')

    config = Configuration(package_name='mypackage', parent_name=parent_package, top_path=top_path)
    config.add_extension(name='_mypackage',
                         sources=[mypackage_gen_source],
                         extra_f90_compile_args=f90flags,
                         f2py_options=['--quiet'],
                         )
    return config

def mypackage_gen_source(ext, build_dir):
    # ... some code that assembles a list of file paths called sourcelist
    config.have_f90c()
    return sourcelist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(configuration=configuration)
```

Is there any way to tell numpy.distutils to use *different* flags for different files?

If this is not possible, what is a better way to build and package a big project like this?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is any supported way to do this, but to see a monkey patch that works well: https://github.com/brian-rose/climlab/blob/master/setup.py